# cómo conservar objeto InputStream aún después de usarlo en un BufferedInputStream java?

Tags: java, file

Tengo este código:

```
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
    if(client.isConnected()){                        
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        System.out.println("Aqui si tiene: "+fileContent.available());

        BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
        buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileContent);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        boolean foo = client.storeFile(imgBD.get("nombre"), buffIn);

        //si se guardó bien en el FTP entonces guardamos en el disco local del servidor
        if(foo){ 
            String fileName = getSubmittedFileName(filePart);
            File folder = new File(ruta+File.separator+imgBD.get("carpeta"));
            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(ruta+File.separator+imgBD.get("carpeta"), imgBD.get("nombre"));                
            System.out.println("Aqui ya es cero "+fileContent.available());
            Files.copy(fileContent, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
    }
```

Tengo que pasar mi objeto *fileContent* en un **BufferedInputStream** para poderlo guardar en un FTP, hasta ahí todo bien, pero parece que esa línea hace que mi objeto **InputStream** (*fileContent*) se convierta en **0 bytes**. En mi primer *System.out.println* me imprime bien los bytes que tiene el objeto y en el segundo *System.out.println* me imprime un 0, por lo que sí crea una imagen en el directorio que quiero pero con 0 bytes, osea que es un archivo con el puro nombre.

Cómo hago para usar mi objeto **InputStream** aún después de que sea utilizado por **BufferedInputStream**?

Comment: Te pregunto, en el método del client.storeFile(imgBd.get("nombre"), buffIn), se está guardando algo!? Asumo retorna True (solo por que llega al otro system.out.prinln) pero realmente almacena algo!?

Comment: De forma inmediata lo único que puede hacer es tener dos `InputStream` antes de pasar el original al `BufferedInputStream` y esto lo puede hacer clonandolo `InputStream fileContentClone = fileContent.Clone();`

Comment: @isaac ¿Y si el `InputStream` no implementa `Cloneable`? No todo se puede clonar, **especialmente si está relacionado con recursos del sistema** (como archivos).

Comment: ¿De qué clase es instancia `filePart`?

Comment: @Rostan evidentemente guarda algo.

Comment: @isaac No puede ser clonado

Comment: @SJuan76 es instancia de Part igual ya lo resolví

Comment: Si, verifique la documentación y @SJuan76, tienen razón este no puede ser clonado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de un InputStream crear dos InputStream iguales:

```
InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileContent.available()];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = fileContent.read(buffer)) > -1 ) {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    baos.flush();

                    InputStream e = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
                    InputStream e2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Por ahí iba yo. Con la advertencia de que si hay muchos datos igual conviene, en vez de en un `ByteArrayOutputStream` (que se guarda en memoria), guardar los datos en un fichero temporal.

Comment: Cómo puedo lograr eso? Porque realmente lo que estoy enviando son fotos de hasta 5mb

Comment: `File tmp = File.createTempFile(); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmp);` y a partir de ahí tal como lo tienes. Cada vez que necesites leer el fichero, creas un `FileInputStream` de `tmp`. Los principales inconvenientes son que es más lento y que, en según que SO, igual no te deja tener dos `InputStream` abiertos al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Y cuánto tiempo puede estar un archivo en temp?

Comment: Hasta que lo borres, crearlo como temporal solo significa que Java se encargará de darle un nombre no repetido y que por defecto ira a la carpeta de archivos temporales del SO.

Comment: Gracias!.......